# Alignment of tabular objects inside a horizontal box

Tags: tables, boxes

How to align two tabulars of different height side by side so that both top rows are aligned with each other?

Example:

```
\hbox{\vtop{\hbox{Foo}\hbox{Bar}}\enskip\hbox{Baz}}
```

produces

```
Foo Baz
Bar
```

Given two tabulars:

```
\def\tabi{%
  \begin{tabular}{r}
    Foo \\ Bar 
  \end{tabular}}

\def\tabii{%
  \begin{tabular}{r}
    Baz
  \end{tabular}}
```

How do I get the same output? This:

```
\hbox{\tabi\tabii}
```

puts the second tabular at the centre of the horizontal box, which is not what
I want.

Comment: Use `\begin{tabular}[t]{r}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default placement of the reference point for a `tabular` (which makes a box) is midway from top to bottom (it uses internally `\vcenter`). But `tabular` has an optional argument for telling we want a `\vtop` or a `\vbox`:

```
\newcommand\tabi{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{r}
    Foo \\ Bar 
  \end{tabular}}

\newcommand\tabii{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{r}
    Baz
  \end{tabular}}

\mbox{\tabi\tabii}
```

For alignment with respect to the bottom row, it's `\begin{tabular}[b]{...}`